# Sorting floats with exponents with 'sort -g' bash command

Tags: bash, sorting, command-line

I have a file with floats with exponents and I want to sort them. AFAIK 'sort -g' is what I need. But it seems like it sorts floats throwing away all the exponents. So the output looks like this (which is not what I wanted):

```
$ cat file.txt | sort -g
8.387280091e-05
8.391373668e-05
8.461754562e-07
8.547354437e-05
8.831553093e-06
8.936111118e-05
8.959458896e-07
```

This brings me to two questions:

1. Why 'sort -g' doesn't work as I expect it to work?
2. How cat I sort my file with using bash commands?

Comment: What's the version of your `sort`?

Comment: It works for me (GNU sort). Read [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html) pay particular attention to the footnote.

Comment: potong: thanks, that solved the problem. Seems like the locale I had (ru_RU.UTF-8) doesn't treat dot as a decimal separator.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that in some countries local settings can mess this up by using `,` as the decimal separator instead of `.` on a system level. Check by typing `locale` in terminal. There should be an entry

```
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
```

If the value is anything else, change it to the above by editing the locale file

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/locale
```

That's it. You can also temporarily use this value by doing

```
LC_ALL=C sort -g file.dat
```

`LC_ALL=C` is shorter to write in terminal, but putting it in the locale file might not be preferable as it could alter some other system-wide behavior such as maybe time format.

Comment: @Teemu I edited this old post so now it should be more appropriate:) I did not have the permission to comment when I wrote the first one.

Comment: Yes, the best one

Answer (score 9):

Here's a neat trick:

```
$ sort -te -k2,2n -k1,1n test.txt 
8.461754562e-07
8.959458896e-07
8.831553093e-06
8.387280091e-05
8.391373668e-05
8.547354437e-05
8.936111118e-05
```

The `-te` divides your number into two fields by the `e` that separates out the mantissa from the exponent. the `-k2,2` says to sort by exponent first, then the `-k1,1` says to sort by your mantissa next.

Works with all versions of the `sort` command.

Answer (score 3):

Your method is absolutely correct

```
cat file.txt | sort -g
```

If the above code is not working , then try this

```
sed 's/\./0000000000000/g' file.txt | sort -g | sed 's/0000000000000/\./g'
```

Convert '.' to '0000000000000' , sort and again subsitute with '.'. I chose '0000000000000' to replace so as to avoid mismatching of the number with the inputs. 
You can manipulate the number by your own.

Comment: potong already solved my problem in the comment to my question. The locale I had (ru_RU.UTF-8) doesn't treat dot as a decimal separator. The solution is to set LC_ALL environment variable to 'C'.