# bash sort -g for x.xxe+x format numbers in Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sorting

Tried to sort (GNU coreutils 8.21) some data in ubuntu 14.04LTS using sort **-g** but didn't sorted as I expected:

```
printf "1\n6.7\n9\n6.9\n8\n1e4\n7\n1e+3\n2\n4\n45\n1e-2\n0.2e+3\n1.1e2\n1.2e+2" | sort -g
```

Returns

```
0.2e+3
1e-2
1
1.1e2
1.2e+2
2
4
6.7
6.9
7
8
9
45
1e+3
1e4
```

Seems to work on `x, x.x` and `xex` formats but not with `x.xex` numbers. Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: Works fine to me on `sort (GNU coreutils) 8.21`.

Comment: Use echo with `-e`. echo without `-e` doesn't interpret linebreaks. Even better use `printf`: `printf "1\n6.7\n9\n6.9\n8\n1e4\n7\n1e+3\n2\n4\n45\n1e-2\n0.2e+3\n1.1e2\n1.2e+2" | sort -g`

Comment: I doubt that this is the command you ran, `echo` would print literal `\n`s.

Comment: Works for me using `sort (GNU coreutils) 8.13`, `sort (GNU coreutils) 8.15` and `busybox sort v1.18.5`.

Comment: The original question had `printf`, only that @Robel changed it on his suggested edit http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5644618

Comment: Still giving me the same output sort (GNU coreutils) 8.21 and ubuntu 14.04LTS

Comment: I ran the exact command you show in your problem statement (copy/paste) and did not get your results. I got the correct results. If you ran something different and saw unexpected results, please edit your question and show what you actually ran and the actual results.

Comment: I ran that code, ![snapshot](http://i59.tinypic.com/b7givn.png)

Comment: Ok, that's interesting and weird. For the record, my version of GNU coreutils is 8.15. I'd have said something may be broken in version 8.21, but @fedorqui is saying 8.21 works for him. Just to be very picky, when you did your last execution, did you copy/paste from your problem above? That's how I did it. Kind of a long shot, but just to be sure there's no hidden characters somewhere.

Comment: I got the same result. I had some scripts in ubuntu 12LTS using sort -g working fine, but when I fresh installed 14LTS the scripts began to fail because sort -g was not sorting properly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the exact same problem and the same OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. The solution for me was

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/locale
```

and add/replace this line

```
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Probably you are not in the US, and some local settings are messing it up. found tips for this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311624/sorting-floats-with-exponents-with-sort-g-bash-command). One possible workaround if this doesn't help can be the following if all entries contain an E (or e or d or whatever)

```
sort -s -tE -k2g -k1g fil.ext
```

This uses an `E` (`-tE`) as the column separator and first sorts by the second column (`-k2g`), that is the exponent, and then by the first column (`-k1g`), i.e., what is before the exponent. This seemed to work for me. My data looks like this

```
0.13000000E-03  6 0.37947329E-11   0.53072241E-11   
0.13000000E-03  5 0.39614807E-11   0.51917483E-11   
0.15511087E-03  6 0.35497942E-11   0.50973016E-11   
0.16372814E-03  7 0.34271161E-11   0.49932135E-11
```

Comment: You can pass the locale to just the sort command like: printf ... | LC_ALL=C sort -g

Comment: @JonatanÖström thank you! That solve the problem! As you said i'm not in the US.